# How does an magnetic resonance guided focused ultrasound (MRgFUS) machine work?

Tags: acoustics, applied-physics, medical-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

As a medical application, magnetic resonance guided focused ultrasound (MRgFUS), is new I the treatment of some parkinsonian diseases, prostate cancer, none problems, and more. However, I am not sure how this works and how it differs from chemotherapy or laser treatment. Would you be able to shed some light on this and how these ultrasounds are different from other ultrasounds?

Answer (score 0):

Focused ultrasound uses a continuous beam of ultrasound focused to a small volume for treatment.  Typically used to heat small volumes of tissue for ablation.  Chemotherapy is generally a systemic therapy, and laser treatments are usually limited by treatment depth due to light scattering in tissue.

Unlike ultrasound imaging, which uses pulses of sound waves and listens for the returning echoes, focused ultrasound therapy uses a continuous beam of sound which means you can't do any imaging with it.  You need to use some other imaging modality to determine the position of the volume you want to ablate.  Ideally, the imaging is done simultaneously with the  ultrasound so there's no worry about your volume moving around between imaging and treatment.

This is where the MRI part comes in.  Build a focused ultrasound that can be integrated and operated in an MRI environment, do MRI to localize your region and get your ultrasound pointed at the right spot.  MR can track the volume if it moves (during respiration for example) and allow the ultrasound system to move the focus point accordingly.  The MRI is also used to monitor tissue changes during the therapy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How is the simultaneous imaging carried out by MRI, if no information can be recovered from the area of incidence of the focused beam itself? How can MRI see sound waves?

Comment: You  have misunderstood.  I didn't say that no information can be obtained from the target volume.  I said that you can't do imaging with the focused ultrasound beam.  The MRI doesn't see the sound waves.  MRI is being used to image the area being treated, not the ultrasound.